# MySQL Cluster Failover doesn't work

Tags: mysql, failover, cluster

I have two servers, where

First server 10.100.15.150:
1. one mgm server
2. one ndbd
3. one mysql api

Second server 10.100.15.160: 
1. one ndbd
2. one mysql api

When i start all 'parts' of cluster it looks :

### Cluster Configuration

[ndbd(NDB)]     2 node(s)

id=21   @10.100.15.150  (mysql-5.1.56 ndb-7.1.17, Nodegroup: 0)

id=22   @10.100.15.160  (mysql-5.1.56 ndb-7.1.17, Nodegroup: 0, Master)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)

id=3    @10.100.15.150  (mysql-5.1.56 ndb-7.1.17)

[mysqld(API)]   2 node(s)

id=11   @10.100.15.150  (mysql-5.1.56 ndb-7.1.17)

id=12   @10.100.15.160  (mysql-5.1.56 ndb-7.1.17)

When i shutdown first machine - 10.100.15.150, on second the nbdb process also has been shutdown so i cannot use this data node and cluster fail ...

How i must configure this cluster to get FailOver working ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. In this case, the ndbd on server2 can't determine that it is the only viable cluster (because server1 shutdown), or if server1 is still working but just can't communicate with server2. Note that shutting down server2 would allow server1 to continue to run because the mgm server is running on server1.

Two options:

1.) Run a a second mgm on server2. This will allow for planned failovers, by shutting down the mgm on server1, allowing the server2 mgm to takeover, and then shutting off server1.

2.) Get a third server for the mgm.